# "Are you challenged to lead your house?"

Tags: word-usage

In Martin Scorsese's new film *Killers of the Flower Moon*, I heard a line from Robert De Niro's character:

> Are you challenged to lead your house? (Leonardo DiCaprio's character answers: No)... You've got to take back control of your home. (on p.57 of [this script](https://deadline.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/Killers-Of-The-Flower-Moon-Read-The-Screenplay.pdf), thanks to @Lambie)

This strikes me as non-idiomatic at least in the English variety I'm most familiar with. Normally "to be challenged to do" means "to be invited to do something" or "to be provoked/dared to do something" but here the context makes it clear that it means "having difficulty doing something". I find this use very unusual and it immediately stood out. I would probably use here "challenged in leading your house" or something entirely different.

I don't want to assume but this movie is set in the 1920s' Oklahoma and characters, especially Robert De Niro's character, use a lot of quirky or dated turns of phrase. So is this a dated use? Dialectal?

Comment: Do you have a link to the clip in question?

Comment: @alphabet copyright issues. I can't find it online.

Comment: Have you looked in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/challenge)? This sense seems still current in examples like "an event that challenges explanation" or even a "challenging job". Although "Does leading your house challenge you?" or "Is leading your house challenging for you?" would be a more normal way of asking it, and "challenged to" seems a bit odd compared to "challenged by". So maybe there are questions there.

Comment: I haven't seen the movie or read the book, but does De Niro's character ever speak like a preacher, using turns of phrase one might hear in a sermon?

Comment: @StuartF It isn't so much the semantic sense as the non-finite  clause complement that is unusual.

Comment: 'Is it a challenge to lead your house?' might have been more idiomatic, but the unusual often adds punch / atmosphere.

Comment: Here's the script: https://deadline.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/Killers-Of-The-Flower-Moon-Read-The-Screenplay.pdf Reminder: Not everything in books and movie scripts is already written. lead a house means: "act like a man and be the leader of your family" here.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for that! Yes that's what I understood it to mean.

Comment: @TimR Yes! It doesn't make it clear in the film but several instances hint at that. The scene I'm referring to in the question has a pulpit-style stand with what seems to be a Bible on it. Also someone calls De Niro's character "Reverend Hale", but it only occurs once as far as I can remember. On a similar note, I went through all the examples I could find on Google Books of "are you challenged to..." and surprisingly a lot of those texts were religious/Christian themed. And all of them seemed to use this phrase in the sense I am familiar with, in a positive way.

Comment: @desmo: It certainly invoked the conservative pulpit for me  and I was reminded of "The Jezebel Spirit" on the album *My Life in the Bush of Ghosts* by David Byrne and Brian Eno.